# Unable to ssh ProxyJump AD / PAM user to jumpbox / bastion host

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm trying to ProxyJump an ActiveDirectory/PAM user via a Bastion Host to AWS EC2 instance

If I try to login "per-server" i.e. log in to Bastion Host with AD/PAM credentials I can login. From the Bastion Host I can then use my AD/PAM user to login to the EC2. So there isn't an issue on this.

Step1: `ssh user@example.com@bastion.example.com` - I can login to the Bastion

Step2: `ssh user@example.com -h 1.2.3.4` - I can login to the EC2 at IP 1.2.3.4

Now I want to use ProxyJump but the user and/or domain and/or bastion.example.com if malformed / incorrect when I check logs. So from what I can gather, I should be able to do something like:

```
ssh -J user@example.com@bastion.example.com user@example.com 1.2.3.4
```

From the Bastion Host I get following connection:
`debug1: Setting implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump: ssh -l user -v -W '[%h]:%p' example.com@bastion.example.com`

`debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -l user -v -W '[example.com]:22' example.com@bastion.example.com`

`Authenticating to bastion.example.com:22 as 'example.com'`

I have tried `-l` switch and removed `-J` which come through correct but lose the ProxyJump feature

`ssh -v -l user@example.com bastion.example.com user@example.com 1.2.3.4`

`debug1: Authenticating to bastion.example.com:22 as 'user@example.com'`

Which is correct..

Any advice how I can ssh ProxyJump into a Basion Host with AD credentials? Do I need escapes in the command somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I've had to resort to using following ProxyCommand which works

`ssh -v -o ProxyCommand="ssh -v -l user@example.com -W %h:%p bastion.example.com" user@example.com@1.2.3.5`